# Handling buffer data obtained from rs232 port

Tags: c#, buffer, port, buffering

I have a project in which I am expected to read data from a scale using rs232. The output from the scale is in the format "L00000".My problem is that the scale sends data continuously as it weighs like "L00000,L00001,L00002,L00003,L00004". My interest in this case is to obtain the last part "L00004" to be stored in the db.
Here is my code: Kindly help me improve it. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
 {
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<byte> PortBuffer = new List<byte>();
    SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (comPort.IsOpen)
        {
            comPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            MessageBox.Show("Data cleared");
            comPort.Close();
        }

        if(!comPort.IsOpen)
        {
        comPort.Open();
        //sample of data as written by the scale. How can I get the last chunk only so that I format it for my needs
        comPort.Write("L00002 L00002 L00002");

        int bytes = comPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        comPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        comPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(data_received);

        comPort.Close();
       }
       }
    public void data_received(object sender,SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test" + comPort.ReadExisting().ToString());

    }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the data seperated, is the a space a , or no seperation?

If its a , like in the question then

```
var data=comPort.ReadExisting().ToString();
var result=data.Split(',').Last();
```

Comment: No , hence I replaced it with a space in Split(' ') but it seems not to work. Do you think I captuered my buffer data well in:
      `code`  int bytes = comPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytes];
        comPort.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

Comment: Yes, I think you've already read the data into buffer. Remove the read commands in the first code.

Comment: Remove those 3 lines and then post the exact data you get out of the message box?

Comment: Thank you so much it worked.I simply removed the 3 lines an got the expected result.i.e LXXXXXX.
It works even in the real scale.Thanks alot.